# Images are not showing in localhost

Tags: media

I have taken a clone of my site, downloaded the files folder and the database to my local system.

I am using Xampp server in my local system and I have kept the site image ‘files’ folder in the sites/default/files directory.

The problem is that in my local system 30% of the images are not displaying in the local site. The images are available in the files/images folder,
but in local site the images are not showing.

I tried all the process and i also updated the base url in my setting.php file but the issue is not yet fixed.

According to my understanding the issue is related to the image path. In site those images we are calling through css is not taking the site base url. For example:

Current path:
http://www.localhost/sites/default/files/images/mobile-block-img-new.png

Correct path: http://www.localhost/repliconwebsite/sites/default/files/images/mobile-block-img-new.png

Please suggest if you get the solution.

Comment: Have check you public file system path in Configuration >> Media >> file system?

Comment: @ Vimal Goradiya , Yes i checked, this is my public path "sites/default/files"

Answer (score 1):

As you are using subdirectory structure at localhost and previous drupal installation was at root directory, the base url will not change for database entries.

Use [Pathologic](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathologic) module to change base url of urls coming from database

or

search n replace them in .sql file, then import the database.

search: src="/sites/default/files/images

replace: src="/repliconwebsite/sites/default/files/images

Comment: I kept my sites/default/files folder in root of the server"htdocs folder", so now images are coming but it is not a solution..

Comment: Careful with a search and replace on a dump file. You can destructively change serialized text blobs with matching text but not update the appropriate string length values. If you go this route, check out https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/ Both WP and Drupal use serialized data structures.

Comment: Better use pathologic module

Comment: Plus 1 for pathologic, great module, takes a little working out the configuration.  However I don't think it'll work for images from image fields (it's a text input filter so only works for images uploaded into text fields).  For that I'd consider putting an alias or symlink (or whatever the windows equivalent is) in place so that `sites/default/files/images` points to `/repliconwebsite/sites/default/files/images` saves you hacking the db.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check, whether your files are in `sites/default/files/` folder or `/sites/all/themes/your_theme/images/` folder ? If your files are in `sites/default/files/` folder, You need to change permission and it is not right place to put your images. You should put images in your `/sites/all/themes/your_theme/images/` folder and in `Src` attribute of `image tag` give path from `sites/all/themes/your_theme/images/mobile-block-image.png` path.

Comment: my images exist in sites/default/files/ folder, generally we kept all the images here only,in themes/image folder we kept only site related images. my issue is In site those images we are calling through css is not taking the site base url. and those images we are calling directly in the node images are coming properly

Comment: my problem is same like this https://www.drupal.org/node/445522

Comment: From where you are uploading your images?

Comment: manually i am keeping images in to files/images folder, its working at live and other 4-5 live other servers, but only in local images are not appering but images exist in folder, css images is taking this path http://www.localhost/sites/default/files/images/mobile-block-img-new.png  but my correct path is  http://www.localhost/repliconwebsite/sites/default/files/images/mobile-block-img-new.png